# How to access a value in another control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have two controls on one page and need to access another control's values. 
I believe doing something like `me.page` .... something along theses lines but much help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Page.FindControl method.

[How To Access One UserControl from Another Using ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=155)

Answer (score 0):

If its on same page, you can directly access it.